# iOS bluetooth without GameKit

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth

I already know that using GameKit, I can only connect to other iOS devices running the same app.

But I want to connect to a Parallaz EasyBluetooth chip to send and receive commands, so I need a different solution. I suppose there are some libraries for jailbroken devices, but I don't know any. Can you give me some names or hints to look for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this maby what you need?
http://code.google.com/p/btstack/